# Java thread pool size (Executors)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that has 3 threads which I'm going to switch over to be managed by ScheduledExecutorService. When creating an instance of this you must specific the thread pool size but what is this? Does this mean if I'm planning on running 3 tasks I should create a thread pool size of 3 one for each?

Comment: how are you creating that ScheduledExecutorService?

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);    
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 0, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming You have created **ScheduledExecutorService** like this

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});

executorService.shutdown();
```

Now what is happening here :

- First an ExecutorService is created using the `newFixedThreadPool()`
  factory method. This creates a thread pool with `10 threads`
  executing tasks.
- Second, an anonymous implementation of the Runnable interface is
  passed to the execute() method. This causes the Runnable to be
  executed by one of the threads in the ExecutorService.

> **Thread pools** manage a pool of worker threads. The `thread pools` contains a work queue which holds tasks waiting to get executed.

**Now  Coming to :**

> Does this mean if I'm planning on running 3 tasks I should create a
>   thread pool size of 3 one for each?

Yes so that all 3 task can be executed parallely .

Now here is a nice article about [How big should our thread pool be?](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Thread-Pool-Performance-Tuning)